# Searching on a website

Tags: python, searchbar

I am trying to visit the website and post "python course" into search. There is no error, I can access the website but the only thing I can get is the main page. It seems like I can't put the words "python course" into search and I have no idea why. thank you for help

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = "https://wwww.pythonprogramming.net/search"
values = {'q':'python course'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values) 
data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
repData = resp.read()
print(repData)
```

edit:
As I've said, I have no problem accessing the website. But if you actually go to the website and manually type "python course" into the search bar, you'll get a different result than with python. Through python, the print function only prints the main page for me but no sign of the thing I was searching for (words, phrases). However, if you change the url variable in the code and you search for "pythonprogramming.net/search/?q=python+course, you will get what you want

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: @thaavik: The second sentence in the question says *There is no error*, so it's pretty pointless to ask again.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have four w's: `wwww`
Change to:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse

url = "https://www.pythonprogramming.net/search/"
values = {'q':'python course'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('UTF-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
repData = resp.read()
print(repData)
```

Comment: As I've said, I have no problem accessing the website. But if you actually go to the website and manually type "python course" into the search bar, you'll get a different result than with python. Through python, the print function only prints the main page for me but no sign of the thing I was searching for (words, phrases).  However, if you change the url variable in the code and you search for "https://www.pythonprogramming.net/search/?q=python+course, you will get what you want.

Comment: You have https:// **wwww** .pythonprogramming.net/search/" `urllib` will not resolve this subdomain. Perhaps your browser will know that you meant www and change this for you.  For me it tells me that there is an invalid SSL certificate (because they probably did not map wwww subdomain) so that's how I found the issue in your code.

Answer (score 2):

The only real issue is too many `w`'s in your URL. If you aren't bound to urllib, I'd suggest using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). Same output with less code.

```
import requests

payload = {'q': 'python course'}
request = requests.get('https://www.pythonprogramming.net/search', params=payload)
print(request.text)
```

Comment: This finally helped and enabled me to get the search results I wanted. thanks

Comment: @Tom-as If you need to get certain information from the source, use BeautifulSoup. Glad to have helped, please consider accepting the answer.